# When should a question be transferred to Chemistry.SE?

Tags: discussion, scope, allowed-questions

I've just [asked a question](https://health.stackexchange.com/q/13299/8212) that one could argue should be migrated to Chemistry.SE.

What is the community's stand on that? **Should we accept questions regarding drug metabolism and interaction of medication with body processes?**

I'd say yes because any good answer would be a combination of biology, chemistry and anatomy, thus Health.SE is the only option to ask such questions (it would be most certainly off-topic at Biology.SE and probably also at Chemics.SE)

Comment: I do hope we accept such questions!  I love when those are asked.  I'd originally hoped and tried to foster much more of those kinds of discussions here, to minimal avail.  Health is at its foundation physiology.  I am not veteran enough a user to speak for this site, so I will leave my thoughts here as a comment.  It overlaps for certain; it could be asked on Bio, and Chemistry likely as well, but it certainly has a role here.  It might be an interesting experiment to post on all 3 and see which gets more/better answers?